# How to tell a FieldEditorPreferencePage to invalidate/redraw programatically?

Tags: java, layout, swt

I defined a custom FieldEditorPreferencePage. In createFieldEditors method I construct a simple interface with a custom FieldEditor that holds button that loads a file. When a user loads the file the interface region (where the button stands) need to change and show other specific gui. How to invalidate the FieldEditorPreferencePage? I used the layout() method of the parent composite but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class MyPage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage {
    ...

    private Composite fieldEditorParent;
    private boolean fileLoaded = false;

    @Override
    protected void createFieldEditors() {

       fieldEditorParent = this.getFieldEditorParent();

       MyFieldEditor compositeFieldEditor = new MyFieldEditor(fieldEditorParent) {

        
       if(fileLoaded) {
           //draw file content
       } else {
           Button chooseButton = new Button(buttonsComposite, SWT.NONE);
           chooseButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            
                    //choose file
                    fileLoaded = true;

                    //invalidate page <-- THIS DOES NOT WORK!
                    fieldEditorParent.layout(true, true);
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `layout` just adjusts the positions of controls it does not 'invalidate' the page or cause anything to reload its contents. How is this file load changing preference values?

Comment: Well do be honest my code is not preference oriented. I have to integrate a more dynamically changing solution into an existing preference editor. The file has nothing to do with the preference file, the file it is just a library from which I can "read" some UI elements that need to be displayed. Is there maybe a better approach? Thx @greg-449

Comment: Then you should probably be just using `PreferencePage` and putting ordinary SWT Controls on the page. `FieldEditorPreferencePage` and the various `FieldEditors` are really only for preference store based code.